# How to turn off AutoSave in word/PowerPoint/excel/OneNote, while we open it in browser using SharePoint online?

Tags: sharepoint, ms-word, office365, sharepoint-online, autosave

I am using SharePoint online. when I open document using browser option. Its using autosave. Is there any way we can change settings and turn off the autosave option when user open file in browser ?

[image]

Comment: Hi, this is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question is ***off-topic*** here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the **Microsoft Community** http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word or on **Super User** https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or other forums. If you do post something there, you should delete this question or at least add a link in your question here to the new question there to help others.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, it is impossible to disable auto-save in web client.